# Two side-by-side columns with children and children's children filling 100% minus margins

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm stumped on this one.  I've literally tried everything from floated divs, to absolute\relative positioning, to table-cells.  Perhaps there is a better way to word the question but I am trying to have two columns in a container.  The columns are both of an unknown height since they are filled with dynamic content.  The columns must grow to match each other in height however the columns each contain a "box" with special backgrounds and borders (hence why the I can't just do the margin: -5000px; padding: 5000px; hack).

I also tried jQuery where each box has a "growth factor" at the bottom.  On $(window).load() I calculate the height of each column and set the growth factor on the smallest div to the difference.  This works but you can see the div snapping and I'd rather avoid JS.  I have to wait until $(window).load() due to the fact that one of the columns contains images which influence the height.

I mocked up a [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/M9JWM/)

Here's what I have:

(Link in comments)

Here's what I want:

(Other link in comments)

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
<div>Some stuff on the top</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="column left-column">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">Box Header Left</div>
            <div class="inner-box">
                <div class="random-block-element">LEFT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">LEFT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">LEFT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">I neeed to somehow fill the remaining space.  The "box" (grey) should fill the column and the inner part of the box (this white) should fill the box, leaving the margins and padding intact</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column right-column">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">Box Header Right</div>
            <div class="inner-box">
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="random-block-element">RIGHT</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div>Some stuff on the bottom, I need to be pushed down as the div set grows</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
}

.column { 
    float: left;
}   

.left-column {
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.right-column {
    width: 200px;
}

.box { 
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.inner-box {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.box-header {
    background: #FFFF00;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Heres what I have http://i.imgur.com/UD1ZUP5.png .  Here's what I want http://i.imgur.com/ALEMeWB.jpg

Comment: If you would like to see how a robust framework does it, [check out Foundation 5's equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html) and see the source.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did with display: table , row and cell. Definitely check out that positioning 
http://jsfiddle.net/M9JWM/3/

```
//basic structure
<div class="table">
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">
    Lorem    
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.table{
display: table}
.row{
display: table-row}
.left.right{
display: table-cell}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check heights of each box using jQuery and adjust accordingly.  In addition to the jQuery I added ids to your left and right boxes (like this: `<div class="box" id="left-box">`)

```
var left_height = $('#left-box').height();
var right_height = $('#right-box').height();

if(left_height>right_height){
     $('#right-box .inner-box').css("height", left_height-30);
}else{
     $('#left-box .inner-box').css("height", right_height-30);
}
```

Subtract 30 from the height to adjust for padding.  Add or remove rows and the boxes move in line with each other.

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M9JWM/1/)

Comment: Yeah exactly.  That is the solution I found, but as I mentioned in the OP one of the columns contains images (not shown).  I actually have two invisible "growth factor" divs that I set the height accordingly.  This means I have to wait until $(window).load() since if I do it in document.ready the heights are wrong.  This gives a visible snappy effect and I'd rather avoid JS if I can.

Comment: You can add images to your fiddle using placehold.it, for example placehold.it/100 is a 100 pixel box image.  I can't work on it more now but if you post an updated fiddle I might take a look later.

Comment: @user3727769 actually if you use the `onload` event instead of `domready`, you'll be even worse off in chrome browsers since the load event is fired *before* images are rendered

Comment: The issue is on chrome.  document.ready() seems to fire first thus giving me incorrect heights.  window.load() does it fine but there is a visible snappy effect.  Maybe you are referring to an older version of chrome?